# Is it possible to create an animated gif from a youtube or vimeo location using php?

Tags: php, youtube, gif, vimeo

Just a thought on whether this would be possible really, I thought it would be really cool if I could create animated gifs for embedded videos on the fly. Has anyone seen this done before?

Comment: Possible, yes. Unlikely and difficult, also yes.

Comment: Animated GIFs work well with few frames. Videos (unless they're very short) would have orders of magnitude more frames.

Comment: http://gifsoup.com/ - this site looks like it does what were looking for, and the gifs look pretty good! I was initially wondering whether a straightforward php script could replicate the effect, whilst using embedded video.

Comment: By the way I hear GIFs are now proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

first you'd need to get the video file.  After that you'd have to run it through ffmpeg to create stills from selected frames.

Plenty of guides out there just google away. I refer to [this page](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs) every now and then; there is a command to convert the entire video into an animated gif on there.

Comment: you'd obviously need to have the software on your server and command line access for php to automate this process. I'd imagine there are plenty out there who provide these capabilites.

Comment: Sir! I am a beginner. Does this mean that I need to install a software on server that will download video from youtube to server and then pass it to ffmpeg? All this via an automated process,right?

Comment: you got it. you should be able to write something to do this for you.

Comment: Is downloading the whole video necessary? Please,  is there a way to download only a part of the video on server? Downloading the whole video will affect performance a lot. Thanks in advance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315482/download-only-a-part-of-the-video-in-the-server

Answer (score 1):

I would look in to calling imagemagick on the command line via php.

That will do all the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a professional programmer but I have this idea that u can just segment the video into frames, then use the frames to compose the gifs. Since u are going to be using PHP, u will have to create an extension that creates frames from videos (which is not so simple but possible, in C).
 I wish I could program well in C. I could undertake to create such an extension.